# Why won't gulp create files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm relatively new to node.js and I'm having an issue getting this gulp script working.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('fluxxor', function() {
    return gulp
        .src([
            './node-modules/fluxxor/lib/*.js',
            './node-modules/fluxxor/index.js'],
            { base: './'})
        .pipe(concat('fluxxor.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename('fluxxor.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['fluxxor']);
```

When I run `gulp` or `gulp fluxxor` it runs without error, but does not create either of the files. I've tried without the leading `./` and I've tried absolute paths. I've tried just doing a single file source straight to dest and nothing happens. I've tried debugging using gulp-util and gulp-plumber and nothing is working. I'm doing all of this in cloud 9 if that makes a difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens if you remove the `, { base: './'}` part, and then run `gulp fluxxor`?

Comment: I originally had it without that, but that was something that I tried. I just removed it again and it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: silly question: did you do an `npm install fluxxor` (or `npm install`) to *make sure* the `node_modules/fluxxor` directory even exists? (does it exist right now?)

Comment: Yes, [it exists](http://imgur.com/czgmdP8).

Comment: Ugh. Spend a day spinning my wheels, post to SO, figure it out 5 minutes later. I typed node-modules instead of node_modules. Thanks for being my rubber ducky.

Comment: please post that as your answer in case others need help

Comment: as a question with a typo, technically covered by the "off-topic list", so rather than answer it's probably worth unasking instead. Good to know you found it - well spotted! =)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was a typo. I have node-modules above and it should be node_modules.